# JRE Missing when installing eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

So I'm trying to install Eclipse IDE for Java on my main pc.
I had no problem installing it on my laptop but when trying to install it on my PC I get JRE Missing webpage.

I've installed the JDK and JRE and they are both working. I could use some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also had the problem with eclipse and the JRE.

Try to delete the 2 Java versions and deinstall eclipse.
then install the JDK first and seccond the JRE. after the 2 installations install the new eclipse version(in the installer you chan choose between some installations take the first).

i hope I can help you.

Comment: Oh, is this functionality in the new installer?  I only used the "unpack zip and run"-distribution

Comment: I disable the "Public JRE" option when installing a JDK for this very reason. Eclipse does not need the JRE that is separate from the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Unless explicitly told in `eclipse.ini` Eclipse uses the system wide `java` command.

Easiest for you right now is to install a system wide JRE (same 32/64 bit flavor as eclipse).

Comment: what do you mean? Im sorry for the trouble

Comment: You can edit eclipse.ini to use any JVM you wish. It is the line after "-vm"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was happening when installing different match of JDK version (11 in my case), with JRE (8 in my case).

So, in order to have this installation of Eclipse working make sure that you have both JDK and JRE referring to the same version. Installation will not work if they have different versions.